# How to disable highlighting unsaved documents?

Tags: notepad++

By default, Notepad++ 6.1.4 highlights documents with unsaved changes.

I'm trying to disable this, since I'm using a dark theme and the highlighting is too bright and doesn't look good.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You want to disable Syntax Highlighting completely??

Comment: If you are talking about the syntax highlighting you can go to Language -> Normal Text. Not 100% sure what you mean by unsaved/saved changes highlighting

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this feature cannot be disabled. However, you can edit the executable to replace the icon for unsaved documents with the icon for saved ones.

It's easier than it sounds:

1. Download and install [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).
2. Close Notepad++ (if it's open) and launch Resource Hacker.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and open Notepad++'s executable.

   If it's installed in the default path, just paste `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` in `File name` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> to open the `Replace Icon ...` dialogue.
5. Under `Select icon to replace`, locate the icon for *unsaved* documents (`502` in v 6.1.3).
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and open Notepad++'s executable (`notepad++.exe`) again.
7. Under `Select new icon`, locate the icon for *saved* documents (`501` in v6.1.3).
8. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to close the dialogue and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save the executable.
9. Restart Notepad++.

There's no need to make a backup copy of the executable, as Resource Hacker does this automatically.